# jquery динамичное изменение типа поля

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здраствуйте. Меняю тип поля:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $("#idADDED_SUM_TO_PRICE_SECOND").prop("type", "number");

}
```

и срабатывает корректно ,но при вводе числового значения  выдется предупреждение типа: "`The specified value 111 1 cannot be parsed, or is out of range.`"
Насколько я понимаю ,проблема в пробеле, но в самом поле пробел отсутсвует ,обычное поле типа number со стрелками. В чем загвоздка и куда копать? Спасбо

Comment: вы руками вводите значение, или копируете/вставляете? Если руками, то добавьте сниппет с воспроизводимым примером

Comment: руками, и визуально при вводе пробела тоже нет. Все ,что до 3х цифр ,вводится как обычное число. Если больше 1000 - там и начинаются проблемы